# Simple way to implement a group of queues in Fortran?

Tags: templates, fortran, structure

Suppose that I need to implement at least 5 queues  in one procedure, each of it from a different defined type. How can achive this in a simple and short way?.

Another way to see the question is the way that came to me: after a lot of time of defining my own structures in fortran, I had to make a program in C++, and then I saw how easy is the use of templates... now, I want the same in my mother tongue....

seems that the knowledge is not always confortable

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  Do you mean that you want to create 5 queues, each one of which contains 'objects' of the same type ?  Perhaps you could post your (pseudo-)code to elucidate.

Comment: I mean 5 different queues of 5 different object. Schematically: ***o-o-o-o O-O-O-O 0-0-0-0 @-@-@-@*** and ***x-x-x-x***. So you have to declare each queue and its events 5 times. I suppose that the a pseudo code could be made with 5 modules, each with a very similar code that define a queue and associated procedures, and with the little difference that the object in each node is different. So 5 modules with more than 100 lines and the only difference is that the "type(object1) :: data" must change in each module.... so I am asking for a shorter way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want templates, there is [Pyf95++](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1753167&CFID=175548148&CFTOKEN=50257705). It brings templating and an STL for Fortran using a preprocessor. (for download [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/blockit/index.php?title=Main_Page))

A generic linked-list that uses `transfer()` can be found in [FLIBS](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/FLIBS).

(Otherwise with a bleeding edge compiler you can use unlimited polymorphism as suggested by Richard Lozes.)

Comment: Great ideas!!. I have looking the Pyf95++ program, and sounds very interesting and seems to me a perfect propose to enhance fortran in some next standar. However I find the FLIBS way very usefull and simple. Actually I simplify the code stuff with some preprocesor variables. Now all is good, and I have my fortran templates!! I am very happy. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I post my code in this page http://www.alexispaz.com.ar/fotran-templates, if you wish take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered unlimited polymorphic pointers? See, for ex., pp 269 ff in "Modern Fortran Explained".

Comment: That could be a way, but there is not a penalty related? I have the feeling that a list that have different types in each of its node is a very free list, since you dont know what comes next. I saw an example of this list in 
http://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v3n2a2.htm 
but seems to have many nested objects, is not that a drawback?

Comment: No performance penalty that I know of; select type is executed in much the same way as select case. The drawback is that you lose some amount of type safety.

Comment: USE user_module,    queue_data => user_data  
!     Use next three if user_data contains internal pointers, etc.  
!                   queue_data_Create => user_data_create, &    
!                   queue_data_Destroy => user_data_destroy, &  
!                   queue_data_Copy => user_data_copy  
Make five copies, edit each "user_data" and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented the fortran template in Ruby, which is integrated in my [CodeMate](http://dongli.github.com/CodeMate/index.html). The template syntax is similar to C++. I have implemented double linked list. The template definition snippets are as following:

```
...

template:list_t <type elem_t>
type list_t
    integer :: num_elem = 0
    type(elem_t), pointer :: head, tail
contains
    ...
    procedure :: insert => list_insert
    ...
end type list

...

template:list_insert@list_t <type elem_t>
subroutine list_insert(this, elem, ...)

    class(list_t), intent(inout) :: this
    type(elem_t), intent(out), pointer :: elem

    ...

end subroutine list_insert
```

And the template instance is as following:

```
type(list_t<foo_t>) foo_list
```

where `foo_t` is a user-defined type that extends `list_elem_t<foo_t>`. The you can insert element into `foo_list` by

```
call foo_list%insert(elem, ...)
```

I think my solution to Fortran template is natural.